# How one can safely serialize std::basic_istream<char>::pos_type?

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, stl, char-traits

In one of my projects I have to cache positional information about certain data chunks found in large files. I've already implemented a small API built around `std::basic_istream<char>::pos_type` placed in maps.

Now I need to serialize these descriptors into a bytestream and write them on a disk for further usage (on other *nix-machines as well). I have read that this type is platform-dependent but still rather being a POD-type. So my questions are:

- Whether it will be better to save something besides of just offsets? E.g. `std::fpos<std::mbstate_t>` keeping the state of reading structure?
- How can I safely obtain and restore the offset data from `std::basic_istream<char>::pos_type` (and other info if it is need)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you actually care to serialize the intra-character state?  Are you really using UTF-8 or similar and may need to serialize a position which is WITHIN a single character?

Comment: No I'm only interested in atomic byte offsets. But complain about any hidden states of stream-reading structs that possibly can affect the performance (which does matter for me).

Comment: It sounds like you can just serialize the `streamoff` which is just a number.  Since you say you don't care to serialize intra-character positions, this is enough.  You can store it in an int64_t.

Comment: Ok, apparently I have overthought it.
Thank you, John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of `std::fpos<mbstate_t>` is unspecified and there may be non-trivial state in the `mbstate_t`. You certainly can't portably serialize these objects. You *can* obtain a value of the offset type (`std::streamoff`) which is an integer type and its value can be serialized.

Comment: I've implemented it by static casting the `pos_type` returned by `istream::tellg()` to `std::streamoff`. I guess it is a legitimate way since `char_traits<char>::pos_type` is defined as `std::fpos` which has defined conversion operator to `std::streamoff` as well as ctr according to `std::fpos` [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos). Thank you for answer, Dietmar.